# What is an SL Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an SL Word™.
Find the rule using the examples.

| SL | Not SL |
| --- | --- |
| Take | Give |
| Pine | Oak |
| Mute | Silence |
| Same | Equal |
| Ale | Beer |
| Ten | Twenty |
| Tome | Book |
| Awake | Asleep |
| Awesome | Awful |
| Joke | Jokes |

Here is the CSV Version:

```
SL,Not SL
Take,Give
Pine,Oak
Mute,Silence
Same,Equal
Ale,Beer
Ten,Twenty
Tome,Book
Awake,Asleep
Awesome,Awful
Joke,Jokes
```

**Question:** What is the rule which determins whether a word is an SL Word™?

Hint:

> minimalism

Another hint:

> of good

A third hint:

> TP

A fourth hint:

> constructed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha. I think Scratch--Cat has something rather like the right idea but seems to be missing the *reason*. An SL word is one that

> could (on the basis of its spelling) be a word in the *constructed* language **T**oki **P**ona, one translation of whose name is "language *of good*", whose creator was **S**onja **L**ang, and whose main design principle is one of **minimalism**.

Answer (score 6):

An SL word is what you get when...

> you choose some of these   **s**y**l**lables and put them together to make a word.
>  a i u e o
>  ka ki ku ke ko
>  sa si su se so
>  ta ti tu te to
>  na ni nu ne no
>  ha hi hu he ho
>  ma mi mu me mo
>  ya yi yu ye yo
>  ra ri ru re ro
>  wa wi wu we wo
>  la li lu le lo
>  ja ji ju je jo
>  ga gi gu ge go
>  za zi zu ze zo
>  da di du de do
>  ba bi bu be bo
>  pa pi pu pe po
>  n
>
>  The letters "C" and "V" are disaIIowed.

**EDIT**: What about the hints?

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: I think this is almost right, an SL Word must be rot13(n pbapngrangvba bs wncnarfr cebahapvngvbaf’ nycunorgvpny sbez). One might refer to sources like [this one](https://www.google.co.kr/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fomniglot.com%2Fimages%2Fwriting%2Fhiragana3.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fomniglot.com%2Fwriting%2Fjapanese_hiragana.htm&tbnid=idsXu6swHjYqZM&vet=1&docid=7DSn1AsTmZvYaM&w=600&h=745&hl=ko-kr&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim). Notice how the image suggests slightly different, say tokens, from those given in this answer.

Comment: Still not sure about the hints though :P

Comment: Almost certain that rot13(gurl pna or pbafgehpgrq hfvat uventnan, rkprcg sbe nyr (gurer vf ab yr fbhaq va Wncnarfr, Wncnarfr'f 'e' vf cebabhaprq hfvat xvaq bs n zvk orgjrra Ratyvfu'f 'y' naq 'e' fbhaqf))

Comment: Just curious... why did you use capital `I`s instead of $\ell$ in `disaLLowed`?